# Can I make a Material-Table column render data like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am using a standard Material-Table.  I would like to render the column `status` like in the image down below.  I could use ANT Design to do this, but Material-Table requires a lot less code to allow for searching and filtering.

Here is a very simple example of my table.  I am using some `options` to set the header color, font etc.  I am also using `rowStyle` to alternate colors on each row.

```
const [intakes, setIntakes] = useState([]);
const columns = [
        { title: "Status", field: "Status" },
    ];

function Table() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable data={intakes.intakes} columns={columns} />
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your columns definition, you will need to use the render property of the column object. A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603449/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-create-a-custom-column-with-auto-numbering-in-material)

code example:

```
<MaterialTable       
    columns={[
      { title: "Name", field: "name" },
      { title: "Surname", field: "surname" },
      { title: "Id", field: "tableData.id" },
      { title: "Id+1", render: rowData => rowData.tableData.id + 1 },
    ]}/>
```

This is the important part here:

```
render: rowData => rowData.tableData.id + 1
```

using the rowData, you can call a function here using a specific field other than the id in the example (let's say

```
render: rowData => generateFlagText(rowData.tableData.Status)
```

And your function should return some div with classNames to display those status